# PHP echo to display image HTML

Tags: php, html, image, echo

I am trying to display an image on my webpage using a PHP script to determine which image is displayed.
The image link is as follows:

```
<a href="gallery.php?image=image01">......</a>
```

My PHP script is thus:

```
<?php 
$result = $_GET['image'];
echo '<img src="images/gallery/'.$result.'.jpg">'; 
?>
```

So what I am trying to achieve in terms of HTML is:

```
<img src="images/gallery/image01.jpg">
```

The result I am getting is '"; ?>' displayed on the page.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It appears that your server is not actually executing the PHP, and just spitting out raw text.

Comment: I didn't DV, but based on the looks of it none of the current answers address the OP's issue.

Comment: nope @durbnpoisn i think its because he is not correctly closing the quotes.

Comment: Are these happening at the same time or when you click the link `<a href="gallery.php?image=image01">......</a>`, it will reload to execute `$result = $_GET['image'];
echo '<img src="images/gallery/'.$result.'.jpg">';`?

Comment: Actually it looks like the quotes are closed just fine in the code example the OP has provided. The problem may lie somewhere else in the OP's code @Lal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the gallery.php to this:

```
<?php $result = $_GET['image']; ?>
<img src="images/gallery/<?php echo $result; ?>.jpg">
```

That would simply it a little bit.  You should echo out the result to see what you are getting when the variable is passed to the gallery page.

Comment: You would need to close out your `php` here... `<?php $result = $_GET['image']; ?>
<img src="images/gallery/<?php echo $result; ?>.jpg">` as in @ExCluSiv3 answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your code like this

```
<?php
$result = $_GET['image'];
?>
<img src="images/gallery/<?php echo $result; ?>.jpg">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $result = filter_input ( INPUT_GET , 'image' );
    if (isset($result) && !empty($result)) {
        echo '<img src="images/gallery/'.$result.'.jpg">';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You used echo wrong, here is how you should use it.

```
<?php 
$result = $_GET['image'];
?>

<img src="images/gallery/<?php echo $result ?>.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo"<img src='{$image}'>";
```

`$image = uploads/myImage.jpg`

I think this is the simplest code. To use a php variable while echoing out html, use curly `{}` brackets to insert any php variable. For instance, a file upload...

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $temp_dir=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $image = "img/".$filename;
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php if($row2['pack1']==1){ echo "<img src=".BASE_URL."images/1seo.png";  } ?>
```